# regex - Extract number from string. Number should be first 5 digit from my input

Tags: java, python, regex

I am new to regix.
I want to get only port number from following line:

**Input:**

```
Install: C:\Program Files\app
Database: postgresql://127.0.0.1:42018/app
Started: 2016-12-28 10:40:05.908000
Lines: 1000000
Version: 4.1
PID: 1736
```

I tried following regex,

```
[\d]{5}
```

But it selects all
42018, 10000 and 90800

From the above input, I want to extract only port number `42018`

Comment: What is the programming language? Look, it is easy to *capture* the 5 digit number, as in [`postgresql://[\d.]+:(\d{5})\b`](https://regex101.com/r/QQ3TJP/1).

Comment: I want to do same thing in both java and python. as of now i tried only from http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may *capture* the value you need into a capturing group and access it with the corresponding code.

The regex for both Java and Python can look like

```
postgresql://[\d.]+:(\d+)\b
```

**Details**:

- `postgresql://` - a literal string `postgresql://`
- `[\d.]+` - 1 or more digits or `.` symbols
- `:` - a colon
- `(\d+)`  - Group 1 capturing 1 or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/eNM1BS):

```
String s = "Install: C:\\Program Files\\app\nDatabase: postgresql://127.0.0.1:42018/app\nStarted: 2016-12-28 10:40:05.908000\nLines: 1000000\nVersion: 4.1\nPID: 1736";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("postgresql://[\\d.]+:(\\d+)\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
}
```

See the [Python code](https://ideone.com/ZD0vTT):

```
import re
s = "Install: C:\\Program Files\\app\nDatabase: postgresql://127.0.0.1:42018/app\nStarted: 2016-12-28 10:40:05.908000\nLines: 1000000\nVersion: 4.1\nPID: 1736";
pattern = r"postgresql://[\d.]+:(\d+)\b"
m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure regex is your best option here, depending on the programming language, you may want to extract the port using some libraries.

If you still insist to use regex, you should make it more specific, for example:

```
postgresql:[^:]+:(\d+)
```

Comment: I want to select only 42018. but `postgresql:[^:]+:(\d+)` selects postgresql://127.0.0.1:42018

Comment: @CMY You should get the first group only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex:

> postgresql://(\d+.?){4}:(\d+)/app

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract every five digit number in any cases, use `(?:^|[^\\d])[\\d]{5}(?:$|[^\\d])`. Do not use \b like the answer above. This does not distinguish a boundary of  alphabets and numbers like 44000e, e44000.

Answer (score 0):

regexp to detect protocol://ipaddr:port pattern and capture "port" part of it.
keep in mind, that you should use not whole match but capture gruop value (how to do it - depends on programming language you use).

```
[a-z]+\:\/\/[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\.[\d]+\:(\d+)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{5}(?=\/app)
```

This might help given sample input.